# Flutter deep links not working in any browser

Tags: flutter, dart, android-deep-link

I want to open my application if the required link is entered in the browser. I configured the scheme but it didn't help. Here is my code
[image]

My task is that my guest will also have parameters that I have to return to the application and process there.

my example
myapp://myhost/?code=12213

I want to somehow open the app and process the code. Does anyone know how to do this??

Comment: Have you tried testing it on an Android emulator instead of in the browser?

Comment: @jraufeisen yes, I do all the tests on the emulator. I launch the app, then go to the browser and enter the required URL page, but after that it doesn't come back from the browser to the app